# Why does anchor tag not open target in a new window or tab?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the following code fail to open the target in a new window or tab:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Popup</title></head><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>');" target='_blank'>Click Me</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something pretty basic; but, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: so you click on that link. WHERE in the document would "document.write" work? the exact point on the screen you clicked? the `<a>` tag itself? some random spot at the end of the document? That is a totally incorrect way of inserting text into a document... check your JS console for errors, you'll probably find at least one about abusing doc.write.

Comment: Please include any JS errors you might have in your console

Comment: @MarcB http://jsfiddle.net/e2czv80c/, it seems JSFiddle runs it but runs the javascript void before it runs the blank_ command. Besides, it makes sense that it would write hello world then and there since it is referring to the current document.

Comment: Actually, the content is displayed just fine in the current window and there are no errors shown in the JS console.  The only part that is not working is that the display is in the current window rather than in a new window or tab.  IOW, for whatever reason, the target='_blank' is not doing its job.  I don't see that as being a JS issue.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var win = window.open(null, '_blank');` followed by `win.document.write();` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Example as a link:

```
<a href="javascript:var win = window.open(null, '_blank');win.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Popup</title></head><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>');" target='_blank'>Click Me</a>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/m4qhrre2/

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are writing to the current document.

Comment: @user3311045 will you please upvote and accept if this solution works for you? thanks!